# Is there a number $k$ such that every integer $n\ge 24$ is a sum of at most $k$ squares of a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Suppose, $n\ge 24$ is a natual number. Then, $n$ can be written as a sum of squares of primes (the squares of the primes need not be distinct) because $n$ can always be written in the form $4a+9b$ with non-negative integers $a,b$. 
So, we can find primes (not necessarily distinct) such that $$(1)\ \ \ \   p_1^2+p_2^2+\cdots+p_k^2=n$$

> But is there a positive integer $k$, such that every positive integer $n\ge16$ can be written as a sum of at most $k$ squares of a prime ? In other words, a number $k$ , such that $(1)$ has always a solution ?

Comment: According to my calculations so far, $k=7$ is not sufficient (take $n=32$), but $k=8$ might work.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem, it involves Weyl's and Vinogradov's bounds on exponential sums over squares or primes and Hardy's circle method.  Due to arithmetic constraints $\pmod{8}$, my bet is that every sufficiently large positive integer can be written as the sum of $8$ prime squares, but probably "sufficiently large" means $n\geq N$ with $N\gg 16$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I currently search an $n$, for which $k=8$ is not sufficient.

Comment: It looks like a good idea to add some heuristics and classical methods in additive number theory for dealing with the $p^2$ terms, if there are any.

Comment: what would happen if n is decomposed into 4 squares and then each of these squares is in turn decomposed into 4 squares...until we end up only with primes.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the ["Waring-Goldbach problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%E2%80%93Goldbach_problem).  Waring's problem is of course your problem without the prime constraint, and Goldbach's problem is your problem for first powers.  [This article by Buttcane](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X09002145) states that at least seven, and no more than nine, squares of primes are necessary to express every sufficiently large integer.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not an expert on this. I just know how to use Google and had some time to kill.